# How do I animate the font size of CCLabelTTF?

Tags: objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone, font-size

I would like to perform an animation on a CCLabelTTF, where the font size is being animated. I do not want to use `CCScaleTo` because (of course) then the quality is bad. Has anybody got a clue how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I´m afraid you can not animate font size on a CCLabelTTF, you can set the maximun font size you want for your label  and then use setScale or CCScaleTo. But take notice that CCLabelTTF is slower than CCLabelBMFont, in my opinion is better to render the bitmap font with any program like bmGlyph, and then use CCLabelBMFont, take a look at [cocos2d reference](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_label_b_m_font.html).
But anyway you´ll have to scale the label.